# Why cookie received in "Set-Cookie" response not sent in next request (only FireFox)?

Tags: http, firefox, cookies, browser

I have this issue where I am trying to login to a server(running on my local network). The login works perfectly when using Chrome/Edge but fails on FireFox.

In browser devtools/wireshark I see the server sends a cookie _oauth2_proxy_csrf when I access the login page. This cookie should be included in all future requests from my browser to server.

On chrome

Response from server

```
Server: nginx/1.15.7
Date: Sun, 05 Jul 2020 12:18:43 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 281
Location: http://192.168.0.101/oauth2/oauth2/auth?approval_prompt=force&client_id=oauth2-proxy&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Foauth-proxy%2Fcallback&response_type=code&scope=openid+email+profile+roles&state=472474af0548b13655fd6e8515f0fc31%3A%2F
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC
Set-Cookie: _oauth2_proxy_csrf=472474af0548b13655fd6e8515f0fc31; Path=/; Expires=Sun, 12 Jul 2020 12:18:43 GMT; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
```

chrome next request

```
GET /oauth2/oauth2/auth?approval_prompt=force&client_id=oauth2-proxy&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Foauth-proxy%2Fcallback&response_type=code&scope=openid+email+profile+roles&state=472474af0548b13655fd6e8515f0fc31%3A%2F HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.0.101
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.125 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Cookie: _oauth2_proxy_csrf=472474af0548b13655fd6e8515f0fc31
```

every thing fine, can login if I continue with this flow but

On FireFox

Response from server

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Server: nginx/1.15.7
Date: Sun, 05 Jul 2020 12:21:33 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 281
Location: http://192.168.0.101/oauth2/oauth2/auth?approval_prompt=force&client_id=oauth2-proxy&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Foauth-proxy%2Fcallback&response_type=code&scope=openid+email+profile+roles&state=4b06492a222e53045d0447826a50c47e%3A%2F
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC
Set-Cookie: _oauth2_proxy_csrf=4b06492a222e53045d0447826a50c47e; Path=/; Expires=Sun, 12 Jul 2020 12:21:33 GMT; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
```

Firefox next request (no cookie set)

```
GET /oauth2/oauth2/auth?approval_prompt=force&client_id=oauth2-proxy&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Foauth-proxy%2Fcallback&response_type=code&scope=openid+email+profile+roles&state=4b06492a222e53045d0447826a50c47e%3A%2F HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.0.101
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:80.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/80.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
```

server fails to login (error: no named cookie found)

I have seen other cookie issues on google but I have not seen anything similar to mine.

Comment: All browsers allow the user to opt out of using certain cookies. Firefox's default setting [blocks some cookies](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/disable-third-party-cookies). Try experimenting with this setting.

Answer (score 1):

So the problem was with server's time. It was creating cookies with expire time already in the past `12 Jul 2020 12:18:43 GMT` vs browsers time of September 2020.

Apprently chrome had no issue sending back the cookie in the next request but Firefox discarded the cookie.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but the opposite, works fine on firefox but not on chrome.
setting secure=true while sending a cookie worked for me as the sameSite was set to none.

`res.cookie('cookie', cookie, { httpOnly:true,secure:true, sameSite:'None' })`